# Help understanding the steps needed to prepare a wall for painting after wallpaper removal

Tags: removal, wallpaper

Recently moved into my first home and learning the DIY ropes and one of my first tasks was to remove the wallpaper in the living room, once I removed it (quite easily - thankfully) it seems to have taken some of the paint  off with it that was beneath the wallpaper, not entirely, in patches ranging from large to small.

Now I'm looking for some advice on how to prepare the wall again for repainting and just assessing my options, my thoughts are:

1. Lining paper (not my first choice
2. Skim coat (probably my first choice?
3. Scrape all paint back??

Excuse my lack of knowledge, kind of picking this up as I go.. any help is much appreciated.

Please see the picture to see the current state of the wall post wallpaper.[image][image]

Comment: Remember 2&3 will needs lots of sanding / rubbing down...